# While using scrollIntoView(top) text is hidden inside fixed div in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click link text which is not visible in the screen. So i have used scrollIntoView(top) javascript to make text visible but text moves top of the screen hiding inside header fixed div. So i can't able to click that link. Can anyone please help me to solve this issues

```
 JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
                js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(top);", Loadmoreweb);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently using `top` which isn't a valid input. If you take a look at [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView), there are a couple options.

1. If you pass `true`, the element will be aligned to the top of the page (which doesn't seem like what you want). Passing `false` aligns the element to the bottom of the page, which may or may not be viable. So one option is

   ```
   arguments[0].scrollIntoView(false);
   ```
2. You can pass an Object with three settings. The only one that you seem to be interested in is the vertical alignment. The `block` property controls that. There is a setting for `block` of `"center"` which seems to be what you might want.

   ```
   arguments[0].scrollIntoView({block: "center"});
   ```

There are other options that are outlined in the docs I linked above. Be sure and read them and see which one fits your specific scenario but this should be enough to get you started.

Comment: Thanks 2nd option worked for me. I also found another solution js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", Loadmoreweb); this also works for me.

Comment: @PriyaDharshan Just be aware, when you use a JS click this is no longer a user scenario. JS can click anything anywhere on the page whether it's visible or not, etc. If you are trying to automate a user scenario, use the JS scroll but use the normal Selenium `.click()`. It will fail if the element isn't visible, is blocked by another element, etc. so you will know that a user could actually interact with that element.

Comment: I am using this code action.moveToElement(Loadmoreweb).click().perform(); but it is not clicking correct link text as expected. Can you please me whether i am correct or not?

Comment: I have include thread.sleep() now it is working fine thanks for your advice

Comment: If you use `.moveToElement(Loadmoreweb)`, make sure you add a wait for visible for the `Loadmoreweb` element before doing the `.moveToElement()` call. I'm assuming that's the problem you are seeing.